# How to make internet listener in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to make my application receive notifications from internet so that when my app is installed and internet is connected my app receive notifications from it?

Is the only approach via internet sockets or there are other approaches in mobile development and in specifically Xamarin.Forms?

I've already add notifications to my app via *localnotificationsplugin* pluging with `CrossLocalNotifications.Current` but didn't know yet how to receive notifications from internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a service that facilitates messaging between mobile apps and server applications, You can try to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to get your goal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: Thank you! Does it support both Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS projects? Is it free? Do I need use app center ms to enable it?

Comment: Yes,  If you want to use FCM in ios project, you can take a look the following article:
https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-setup-1961a91d4055

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is free of charge, just like Google Cloud Messaging was. The [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) shows exactly what Firebase features are paid.

Comment: And I don't need to use app center ms to enable it? I will deal only with just Firebase directly?

Answer (score 0):

A very well documented free sdk from OneSignal for xamarin: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup